# Komodo Edit Syntax Checking is not working for PHP files

Tags: komodoedit

I have a computer and a laptop. Komodo Edit v11/v12 works fine on my computer.
Preference settings are exactly the same on both machines.
The problem is on the laptop. I can not get Syntax Checking, or the drop down Option box, to work on PHP files.
Syntax checking and drop down Option box works as expected for CSS, Javascript and HTML files.

I get this notice in the Go to Anything text box:

ValueError: '--- Start of Good Stuff ---' is not in list

Syntax Checking Status (when open in the Status Bar at bottom of window)
Shows no errors or warnings. Even though I create an error.

Have tried:
Help > Troubleshooting > Reset Caches
Help > Troubleshooting > Reset CodeIntel Database
Reloaded Komodo Edit; It was v11, when reloaded only got option for v12. Loaded v12 got same error.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm:
Edit > Preferences > Languages/PHP > Default PHP Interpreter C:\path\to\php\php.exe
Edit > Preferences > Syntax Checking > Langauge PHP > (checked)Check syntax for PHP

Then:
Help > Troubleshooting > Reset CodeIntel Database

Comment: Thanks, I need to set my Interpreter.